# How can I implement the following?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java program that has some number of classes. Three methods taken input A and give output B. I need to make these methods available as a web service so that I can ask something like http://test.com/method?input=A and the result B is returned. I don't want to re-write my existing code. Is there something which is available such as a web service framework for JAVA that can allow me to create a web service interface for these three methods. What is the easiest way?

I have ran into many acronyms and other stuff during my research such as dynamic project, JAVA EE, Glassfish etc... What can implement my requirement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need some sort of web framework -- Glassfish is one example. Basically, your application is not built to receive web requests, so you need some sort of container (e.g. a Servlet Container like Tomcat http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container ).

I think "restlet" is a little servlet container that might suit your needs.

Check it out: http://www.restlet.org/

Comment: I ended up using restlet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do quick Java services I've found is [Restlet](http://restlet.org).

You can use their tutorials to get a webserver up and running like literally 20 minutes from scratch. The Restlet below should work right out of the box as a skeleton framework. You'll replace the call of `String b = ...` of course, and replace it with your own library.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        Component c = new Component();
        c.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 80);
        Application app = new Main();
        c.getDefaultHost().attach(app);
        c.start();
    }

    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/method/{input}", new Restlet(getContext()) {
            public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                String a = request.getAttributes().get("input").toString();
                String b = MyLibraries.compute(a);
                response.setEntity(b, MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
            }
        });
        return router;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a Java EE 6 server, you can use JAX-RS: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I can't understand is, say I have a java program made of multiple classes. Somewhere I have the main method of the Main class that initializes a hash table with data, loads a Graph and builds a quad tree. Now I have three methods that need to be interfaced via a web service which use the loaded quadtree, graph and hashtable loaded in memory. Can the data be shared in this way between the clients?

Comment: The data will stay on the server. The clients in this case are end-users that never actually touch your code, but only receive HTML responses with linked media (css,js,images,etc). So, you will have to build views that represent your data, and the views shouldn't care how the rest of your application works. One thing that's fairly common is to provide data as JSON and use javascript (the only client-side processing you have available to you) to do fun stuff with the data. Also, I think you may have to rewrite your 'main' function to fit with whatever web framework you use.

Comment: Also, each client will probably invoke another instance of your application -- web frameworks usually have a way to make this more efficient (e.g. not redefining the class definition, but creating separate instances) meaning that your data SHOULD be ok, unless you're doing disc IO to the same files or your methods are not thread-safe/multi-process safe (depending on how your web server is configured)